# Meteor with hammer:hammer package: The Hammer variable exists, but is undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor, hammer.js

I am trying to add touch support to my meteor application. I added the package hammer:hammer. It stuffs a hammer_hammer.js file into the document, and creates a variable named Hammer. The problem is, the value of this variable is undefined.

The docs for Hammer.js claim I should just include the library, which Meteor does for me, and start using it like this:

```
var hammertime = new Hammer(element, options);
```

Obviously, this fails when Hammer is undefined. Is there something else I have to do to use it? Is it a bug in Hammer? Or in the hammer:hammer package?

Note that the variable **Hammer** exists, but has the value *undefined*.

**Edit:** I tried copying the entire contents of hammer_hammer.js into the console, and it actually made it work. Of course, I can't keep doing this every time, nor tell the users to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hammer package may not have been published to atmosphere properly.

I investigated the package through source and it looks like the file `package.js` contains an unnecessary `api.export("Hammer");` (since this is already exported by the window). Meteor seems to override the definition with `null`

Looking at it this can be either a bug in Meteor (since its overriding the variable) or an incorrectly published package (for declaring the export). You may want to get in touch with the guys over at Hammerjs who publish it to ask them to remove the  `api.export("Hammer");`

**Updated**: Tracked down the issue to https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/741

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although it's bad news... I assume they know already, so no need to contact them. Not that I found any contact details anyway...
Apparently, according to the issue post, an older version might work. Is there a meteor command to install a specific version of a package?

Comment: Found it. This version works: 
meteor add hammer:hammer@=2.0.4_1